# Rounded thumbnails alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I implemented a kind of rounded thumbnails, but the problem is when my rounded thumbnails go to the next line/row, if the length text of the descriptions of the thumbnails are different it starts getting white gaps.

html:

```
<h2 class="border-bottom">Services</h2>

    <div class="row">
      <article class="service col-sm-3">
      <img class="img-circle" src="images/service-1.png" alt="Icon">
      <h3>CONSULTANCY</h3>
      <p class="service-text">Understanding and addressing organizations’ needs</p>
    </article>

    <article class="service col-sm-3">
      <img class="img-circle" src="images/service-2.png" alt="Icon">
      <h3>IMPLEMENTATION</h3>
      <p class="service-text">Identifying, Identifying, Identifying, training and supporting</p>
    </article>
....
```

[image]

Comment: Please share all the code to reproduce your issue (CSS and HTML)

Comment: The only style is applied is the .img-circle  border radius, the rest is generated by Bootstrap

Comment: If you create new `row` for each 4 `articles` i think that will fix it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You Need to add height to the component as I can see the issue is causing due to in-consistent height you need to apply same height to all the component that will solve your problem. You can apply that via css or you can use jquery to calculate the height of biggest div and apply to rest.

Use this jQuery add "same-height" class where you have sevice col-sm-3 so that it will not conflict with other component.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var maxHeight = -1;
    $('.same-height').each(function() {
      maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
    });
    $('.same-height').each(function() {
      $(this).height(maxHeight);
    });
});
```

For demo check link http://jsfiddle.net/ghayes/fqMK6/4/

Coincidently I have added same answer yesterday for the same issue for your ref [Div is mysteriously moving down after displaying first 3 rows properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087909/div-is-mysteriously-moving-down-after-displaying-first-3-rows-properly/34088304#34088304)

Comment: This is overkill, it's just a CSS float issue, just add a `<div class="clearfix"></div>` after every 4th column that completes the row.  No need to loop over every element twice.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have floated items of different heights that wrap to the next line.  All you need to do is either make a new `.row` for every line, or add a `<div class="clearfix"></div>` after each full row.  no JS is needed, bootstap can handle this by itself.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
    <article class="service col-xs-3">
      <img class="img-circle" src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="Icon">
      <h5>CONSULTANCY</h5>
      <p class="service-text">Understanding and addressing organizations’ needs</p>
    </article>

    <article class="service col-xs-3">
      <img class="img-circle" src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="Icon">
      <h5>IMPLEMENTATION</h5>
      <p class="service-text">Identifying, Identifying, Identifying, training and supporting</p>
    </article>
    <article class="service col-xs-3">
      <img class="img-circle" src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="Icon">
      <h5>Foo</h5>
      <p class="service-text">short text</p>
    </article>

    <article class="service col-xs-3">
      <img class="img-circle" src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="Icon">
      <h5>Bar</h5>
      <p class="service-text">short text</p>
    </article>
    
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    
    <article class="service col-xs-3">
      <img class="img-circle" src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="Icon">
      <h5>CONSULTANCY</h5>
      <p class="service-text">Understanding and addressing organizations’ needs</p>
    </article>

    <article class="service col-xs-3">
      <img class="img-circle" src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="Icon">
      <h5>IMPLEMENTATION</h5>
      <p class="service-text">Identifying, Identifying, Identifying, training and supporting</p>
    </article>
    <article class="service col-xs-3">
      <img class="img-circle" src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="Icon">
      <h5>CONSULTANCY</h5>
      <p class="service-text">Understanding and addressing organizations’ needs</p>
    </article>

    <article class="service col-xs-3">
      <img class="img-circle" src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="Icon">
      <h5>IMPLEMENTATION</h5>
      <p class="service-text">Identifying, Identifying, Identifying, training and supporting</p>
    </article>
</div>
```