# match height each 4 element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to match the height of class "`project_region`" each 4 elements,

```
<div class="grid_new inner_each_pr" onclick="location.href='/region/agroproject/33'">
    <div class="inn_pr">
        <p class="project_region"><b>Московская область</b><br>Животноводство, Строительство сельскохозяйственных объектов | Молочное скотоводство</p>
        <p class="project_name">Строительство животноводческой фермы</p>
        <div class="info_project_down">
            <div class="block_rub inline">
                <p>406 <span>млн. р.</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="block_time">
                <p>8<span>лет</span></p>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The HTML-Code above is inside a `class="row"`, and all `class="inner_each_pr"` are set inline, I tried to do, but it get's me the max height of all elements, I need need to set max height each 4 element.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var maxHeight = -1;
    $('.inner_each_pr').each(function() {
      maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
    });
    $('.inner_each_pr').each(function() {
      $(this).height(maxHeight);
    });
});
```

check this link for details [Div is mysteriously moving down after displaying first 3 rows properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087909/div-is-mysteriously-moving-down-after-displaying-first-3-rows-properly/34088304#34088304)

Comment: I need to find the max height of ".project_region" each 4 elements of ".inner_each_pr"

Comment: I think he means each 4th element, not every element, not sure I understand tho :S

Comment: This script set the max height of inner_each_pr on all elements, I need each 4 elements to find the max height of .project_region